# Do CriteriaQuery code more readable and elegant

Tags: java, hibernate

I wrote the code and would like to change it to more readable and elegant:

```
@Repository
public class ProductRepositoryImpl implements ProductCustomRepository {

private static final int MORE_THEN_RESULT = 1;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public List<Product> findByFilter(Filter filter) {
    final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<Product> cq = cb.createQuery(Product.class);
    final Root<Product> from = cq.from(Product.class);

    try {
        final List<Predicate> predicates = createPredicatesByFilter(cb, from, filter);
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(predicates)) {
            cq.where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    cq.select(from);

    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}

private List<Predicate> createPredicatesByFilter(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<Product> from, Filter filter) {
    final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(filter.getName())) {
        predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(from.<String>get("name")), filter.getName().toLowerCase() + "%"));
    }

    final BigDecimal priceBefore = filter.getPriceBefore();
    final BigDecimal priceAfter = filter.getPriceAfter();

    if (priceBefore != null && priceAfter != null) {
        if (priceBefore.compareTo(priceAfter) != MORE_THEN_RESULT) {
            predicates.add(cb.between(from.<BigDecimal>get("price"), priceBefore, priceAfter));
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    } else if (priceBefore != null) {
        predicates.add(cb.gt(from.<BigDecimal>get("price"), priceBefore));
    } else if (priceAfter != null) {
        predicates.add(cb.lt(from.<BigDecimal>get("price"), priceAfter));
    }

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(filter.getCategory())) {
        predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(from.<Category>get("category").<String>get("name")), filter.getCategory().toLowerCase() + "%"));
    }

    return predicates;
}
}
```

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general this looks okay to me.  In fact I have a similar pattern in
an application with lots of optional filters.  Newer Java 8 features
which can make this a bit nicer (e.g. using `Optional` and method
references).

- Throwing/catching `RuntimeException` like that looks iffy.  At least
  add a message to the exception so the reader knows how to interpret
  this.
- Returning a `List` only to immediately convert it to an array doesn't
  sound that useful, then again, if it's being used from other places it
  might be okay.  `List` also has `isEmpty`, better than having to call
  yet another static function for it.
- [`CriteriaQuery.where`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#where-javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...-)
  is already using the conjunction, no need to add the `and` there.
  Note that the array can be passed for the
  [varargs arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107631/how-to-call-a-vararg-method-with-an-array-of-params):

  ```
  if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(predicates)) {
      cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
  }
  ```
- For the the string matching queries additional helper methods might be
  nice:

  ```
  private static startsWithLower(Expression<String> expression, String pattern) {
      return cb.like(cb.lower(expression), pattern.toLowerCase() + "%");
  }
  ```